# Using LFS with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, git-lfs, team-explorer

I wan't to use Visual Studio 2017 (15.5) together with a Git repository which tracks some files with Git LFS.

I already have Git 2.15, which contains Git LFS, installed on the machine.

I've Visual Studio 2017 installed with only the following workloads and without the Git component since it already is available on the machine:

`--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling`

Visual Studio fails now to checkout branches from the repository since it cannot find Git LFS.

I assume this is because `git-lfs.exe` is not available on the path, and Visual Studio has its own Git instance in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin\`.

If I additionally install the standalone git-lfs installer, which makes `git-lfs` available on the path, checkout works on some machines but not on other (haven't found out what's the difference, maybe installation order or if it was a new installation or update of Visual Studio).

If I remove the `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\` folder everything works fine in Visual Studio, as it does use the Git version available from the path.

My questions are:

1. What is the supposed way to have Git LFS support in Visual Studio?
2. Is there a way to have Visual Studio using the Git Version on the path instead of installing its own instance
3. Does Visual Studio expect git-lfs on the path or should it also work with Git LFS installed through the bundled installer in recent versions of Git for Windows.

Comment: What is wrong with your current work around? Also did you try unchecking the 'Git for Windows' under individual components and just let VS use your current existing Git.

Comment: You mean the workaround of removing Visual Studios Git folder? I don't know if this is a supported scenario or if this is a patched Version of Git and if Visual Studio works with the standard Git installation.

I only install the above mentioned workloads and components. The Git for Windows component is not installed, but Visual Studio still has its own instance of Git.

Comment: VS (from 2017) uses the [MinGit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Git-Windows-Minimal/) (the [link](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git) I think, has MinGit inside it), it doesn't have CLI (but is official Git fork). See [GIT internals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt809117.aspx). It's not entirely clear where the MinGit API stops and CLI picks up. The diff in machines could be due to PATH. Make sure that your PATH (cmd also VS cmd) has the "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\" and you can bump it up. Try reinstalling Git after the VS, using official Git for Windows etc.

Comment: Git is in the PATH on all machines. Also calling `git lfs version` from `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin\` works from all machines, after installing standalone git-lfs (not with only Git for Windows, as `git-lfs` is not on the path in this case). But even then it doesn't work from VS

Comment: You should try order of installation (before or after VS). And maybe raise an issue on G4W GitHub (as those guys are responsible for this as I can tell). And you probably already found the best work around (removing that Team Explorer/Git subdir) if things work after that (VS team tab, changes etc.)

Comment: My question is if removing the TeamExplorer/Git subdir is a supported work around or can lead to some nasty side effects as they depend on this specific version. Unfortunately I couldn't find any answers from Microsoft to this topic

Comment: Also removing the Git subdir is something which needs to be done on every update. And I'm still asking myself what Microsofts official scenario is how they want to support LFS from VS (and they state since VS 2015 U3 that LFS is supported).

Comment: not official (for sure) but if you're having issues with LFS that seems to be 'the' workaround. Have you seen [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/24371/view.html), especially see the last paragraph (`Individual Components Unchecking the "Git for Windows" and click Modify. Then Check the "Git for Windows" and click Modify`), that's why I've said it's probably order of installation (setup issue). Also [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/124942/git-unable-to-push-lfs-issue-in-visual-studio.html).

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of those two issues on the Developer Community. In both issues Microsoft answers that touching Visual Studios Git folder is not a good idea. I, like others on the issue, have also tried to install standalone git-lfs installer to have it in the path, but this doesn't seem to work on all machines. I also think that it is an issue of installation / update order, but I need to solve this in a scripted way for enterprise wide deployment, which I wasn't able to yet

Comment: It seems to work as long as git-lfs is installed before Visual Studio. Installing git-lfs after Visual Studio doesn't work even if git-lfs is on the path.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get Git LFS working with Visual Studio 2017 (15.5.2) it requires Git LFS installed with the [standalone Git-LFS installer](https://git-lfs.github.com/). If Git LFS is installed with the Git for Windows distribution `git-lfs.exe` is not available on the PATH, and since Visual Studio has its own instance of Git, LFS functionality won't work.

It is also important to have Git LFS early in the path otherwise it won't be passed to Git by Visual Studio as the PATH passed to the Git instance run by Visual Studio is limited in the length. For example installing Git LFS after Visual Studio often ends with `git-lfs.exe` too late in the PATH.

Comment: `It is also important to have Git LFS early in the path otherwise it won't be passed to Git by Visual Studio ` this part is important