# Are the git "lfs" and "hooks" folders supposed to be outside of the .git folder?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I've started using git-lfs for a Unity project. After installing git-lfs and committing some resource files, it all seemed to work fine. Now I noticed that there are folders in my working directory called `lfs` and `hooks` that are not inside the `.git` directory. When I do a `git status` git lists the files inside those folders as untracked new files. This is not how it's supposed to work, right? Any ideas what might be causing this and what I should check?

Here is the output:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    Assets/Scripts/PlayerController/FOVKick.cs
        deleted:    Assets/Scripts/PlayerController/LerpControlledBob.cs

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    Assets/Scripts/PlayerController/FOVKick.cs.meta
        deleted:    Assets/Scripts/PlayerController/LerpControlledBob.cs.meta

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        hooks/
        lfs/
```

This is the .gitattributes file in the project root:

```
## Unity ##

*.cs diff=csharp text
*.cginc text
*.shader text

*.mat merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.anim merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.unity merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.prefab merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.physicsMaterial2D merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.physicsMaterial merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.asset merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.meta merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.controller merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf


## git-lfs ##

# Image
*.jpg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.jpeg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.gif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.psd filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ai filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

# Audio
*.mp3 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.wav filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ogg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

# Video
*.mp4 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.mov filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

# 3D Object
*.FBX filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.fbx filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.blend filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.obj filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

# Other
*.a filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.exr filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.tga filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.pdf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.zip filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.dll filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.unitypackage filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.aif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ttf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.rns filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.reason filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.lxo filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Answer (score 5):

Found the culprit.

It was caused by the IDE using a different git executable that didn't have git-lfs installed.

Comment: How did you go about updating the git-lfs on the IDE?

Comment: @CraigP I suppose one could remove "c:\Program Files[ (x86)]\Microsoft Visual Studio\201[7]\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin\" from PATH so that Visual Studio will use the default `git` on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Jawap's answer, it might be possible that Visual Studio doesn't use your git installation due to the PATH being too long ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47921547/4233315)). In my case, it was enough to move the `C:\Program Files\Git LFS` environment variable to the start of the list, and now the two folders are created inside the `.git` directory when I run the program through Visual Studio.